# MVC 3/4 Action Links not triggering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working with some legacy app which I have embedded in iframe in a single page app, could you guys explain why I couldn't use anymore any of the existing links?

```
@Html.ActionLink("name", "action")
```

Could call any of the controllers actions, I had swap them with Ajax action link with post method, I'm wondering what am I missing here? Was the behaviors in previous version of MVC different?
Initially app was in MVC 3 and then finally got upgraded to 4/5.

Comment: What's actual problem?..

Comment: Problem is that I have a lot of @Html.ActionLinks and they don't work and I dont know why, some of them are part of the helpers i.e WebGrid

Comment: Don't work is not a definition of problem. Any errors? Stack trace?

Comment: When clicked nothing completely happens, no errors.

Comment: Show rendered html and check F12 browser console